# Segue to a new version of the current view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

In the popular app Instagram when you click on a user it shows their profile. If you click on another users name (in a comment on a photo maybe) then it shows that second person's profile.

I am trying to achieve something similar using Objective-C and the Storyboard. I have what you could consider an account page and within that page are other users. I can get to one account page but I am running into trouble getting that endless stream of account pages that you would see in an app like Instagram, one of the reasons is you can't perform a segue to the same view controller. I tried to get around it by programmatically presenting a new account page when you click on a new user from within an account page but I ran into lots of errors.

**What is a way that I can achieve that endless stream of the same view controllers** (obviously I am using a `navigationController` since that would probably have been asked of me).

**EDIT** Using the solution provided by @tmac_balla (thank you for the help) I can segue to a new `tableview` but the `tableView` is blank and I get the following error message.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView     _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-  3512.30.14/UITableView.m:7962
2016-01-02 17:06:46.765 Quoter[1631:845864] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x146096000; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1456c19b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1456c0330>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 400}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<_UIFilteredDataSource: 0x145727b20>)'
```

**EDIT 2** Using the solution provided by @Daniel T. I am able to push a new view controller onto the navigation stack and the non `tableView` portion of the controller works fine but when it comes to the cells in the `tableView` I have (in my short testing) see a scenario where the cells do not appear on the new `tableView` but rather appear on the previous one. Not sure if that just is my fault with how I am loading the cells or a problem with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a segue to the same view controller. Here is an example of a button that segues to (another copy of) the view controller it is in.

[image]

Comment: So it is pushing to the new view controller and the view controller is visible. But there is a rather odd bug. Sometimes none of the cells show up on the new view controller and they show up on the previous one. Any help? @Daniel T.

Comment: A new view controller means a new set of cells. Make sure you're initializing them properly.

Answer (score 0):

When the link/button is clicked what you need to do is to push the view controller into your UINavigationController instead of using segues. So when your method is called, you write

```
accountViewController account = accountViewController()
account.someTextField.text = "someText"
self.navigationController.pushViewController(account, animated: YES);
```

which creates a new instance of the same VC and pushes it to the screen.

About the error, try to check if the cell exists and initialize if it does not

```
    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
 }
```

Comment: But how would I make the segue to use in the `prepareForSegue` as I can't segue to the same view controller in storyboard @tmac_balla

Comment: @bretf you do not need to segue to **the same** view. The storyboard just tells you that there exists a segue between one view controller and the other. But actually you create a new accountVC instance for each account when needed (link is clicked). Then you use the back button in the _UINavigationBar_ to go back to previous account.

Comment: @bretf Oh, I see. Nevermind, what you should do is to push the VC into the navigation controller. Edited the answer

Comment: I tried your method (similar to the ones I've tried with some modification) and I got an error message. The message has been added to my question @tmac_balla

Comment: @bretf Ok, so you should initialize the new VC exactly as you do it with the previous one. If you are sure you do it right, them make sure that the cell exists, by checking it first.

Comment: No error that time but it is just showing an empty tableview with a navigation bar at the top. @tmac_balla

Comment: @brettf Well, it means it is ok. Now you just do all the settings for the VC before you call push.